# Отрендерить большую HTML страницу

Tags: javascript, html

Есть следующий код, который должен создавать 16млн элементов (в данном случае только 4к, нужно 16*16*16 заменить на 16*16*16*16*16*16). И после 5млн где то хром сьедает всю оперативку и все. Здесь где то утечка? Что делать?

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');

for (let i = 0, l = 16*16*16; i < l; i++) {
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.style.backgroundColor = '#' + addZero(6, i.toString(16));
    body.appendChild(el);
}

function addZero(digits_length, source){
    while(source.length < digits_length)
        source = '0' + source;
    return source;
}
```

```css
body {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        div {
            width: 1px;
            height: 1px;
        }
```

Comment: Вы такими извращениями canvas имитируете что ли? o_O

Comment: @andreymal типа того.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю это не утечка памяти, а она просто вся занимается. Ваш код без рендеринга обрабатывается ~ за 8 секунд, вес всего html > 700мб, на отрисовке такого кончаются все ресурсы и браузер либо виснет либо грохает вкладку. 
В примере нехватает еще одного *16, превышается лимит на размер string.

```js
var start = Date.now();

const body = document.querySelector('body');
const target = 16*16*16*16*16;

var elms = '';

for (let i = 0, l = target; i < l; i++) {
  elms += '<div style="background-color:#'+addZero(6, i.toString(16))+'"></div>';
}

//body.innerHTML = elms;

function addZero(digits_length, source) {
  while (source.length < digits_length)
    source = '0' + source;
  return source;
}

console.log(Date.now() - start);
console.log(elms.length/1024);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
```